# Cannot access javafx.collections.ObservableList

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm creating a JavaFX application. I started developing it using local SDK and now I was trying to use Gradle. I created the build.gradle as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

application {
    mainClassName='Main.GUI.Main'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.15.2.0'
}

javafx {
    version = "17.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This is part of my code that throws the error javafx.collections.ObservableList:

```
package GUI;

import Main.Archive;
import Main.Document;
import Main.Node;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class MainController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML private TreeView<Node> tagTree;
    @FXML private TableView<Document> fileTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Document, String> name;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Document, Date> date;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Document, Integer> size;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Document, Path> path;

    private static Archive archive;
    private static Main mainApp;

    public void setMainApp(Main mainApp){
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        if(tagTree!=null)
            setTagTree(archive.getTagTree());
    }

    public void setTagTree(Node tags){
        TreeItem rootItem = new TreeItem("Tags");
        if(tags.getChildren()!=null)
            for (Node n:tags.getChildren())
                addNodes(rootItem, n);
        tagTree.setRoot(rootItem);
    }

    // Recursively creates a TreeItem for each tag and adds it to its root
    void addNodes(TreeItem<String> rootItem, Node tags){
        List<Node> children = tags.getChildren();
        // If it's the last item just add it
        if(children.isEmpty())
            rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(tags.getData().getName()));    // HERE
        else{
            // Otherwise, add each child to the root
            TreeItem<String> son = new TreeItem(tags.getData().getName());
            for (Node n : children)
                addNodes(son, n);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(son);    // ALSO HERE
        }
    }

    public void setArchive(Archive archive){
        MainController.archive = archive;
    }

    @FXML
    private void logout(){
        archive.logout();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void addDocument(){
        mainApp.showAddDocument();
    }

    @FXML
    private void addTag(){

    }

}
```

I have similar problems also with javafx.util.Callback and javafx.event.EventTarget.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsi4M.png)

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I don’t know much gradle either and usually figure Maven to the lesser necessary evil for most things, others disagree, it’s just an irrelevant opinion. But look at [openjfx.io gradle JavaFX hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697904/cannot-access-javafx-collections-observablelist).  It doesn’t look like your project.  Get the hello world sample to work in your environment, then integrate parts of your project into the working sample bit by bit, checking everything works for each small addition, until everything works as you want.

Comment: I'm using org.openjfx.javafxplugin. The exact error is java: cannot access javafx.util.Callback class file for javafx.util.Callback not found.

Comment: One issue with your original question is that you have a JavaFX version specified `17.0.1` which does not exist.  It should be `17.0.0.1`.  Downgrading to version `11.0.2` is not a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: If you have an answer, please *do not* edit the question and put the answer there.  Instead, create an answer and put the answer there.  If it is the correct answer, you will be able to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after an amount of time once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jewelsea said, the problem was the version. I was using 17.0.1, which doesn't exist, instead of 17.0.0.1.